# How to populate existing data in bootstrap modal using meteor.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

**addinfo.html**

`<template name="addInfo"> 
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title">Add Art Description </h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <form class="add-image-info">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="title" 
                   placeholder="title" >
              {{title}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Category</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="story" 
                    name="category" placeholder="category">
              {{category}}
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Art Description</label>
                 <textarea class="form-control" id="name" name="artdescription"
                    placeholder="Description ....">
                  {{artDescription}}
                 </textarea>
              </div>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
                 id="save">Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>`

**addinfo.js**

`Template.addInfo.events({
     'submit .add-image-info': function (event) {

```
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageId = Session.get('imageId');
    var a_title = event.target.title.value;
    var a_category = event.target.category.value;
    var a_description = event.target.artdescription.value;

        Images.update({ _id: imageId }, { $set: { title: a_title, category: a_category, description: a_description } });

        toastr.success('Art information added ... ');

        Modal.hide('addInfo');
```

});`

How to populate title,category,description with existing values in the modal ??

Default values with existing data should be present while the modal is opened ..

Comment: you want to show data already there in the db in the modal first. right?

Comment: yeah . existing data should be present while the modal is opened .

Answer (score 0):

```
 Template.addInfo.helpers({
  Images:function(){
 return Images.find();
 }
 });
```

if you have more than one images and you want to show data of specific image then you have to find with some parameters. Also you have to add

```
   <template name="addInfo"> 
  {{#each Images}}
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">..Remaining Code...</div>
   {{/each}}
  </template>
```

Comment: already done using session variable . just need to know how to retrieve existing data in the modal . while popup